# What is the difference between liking similar urls

Tags: url, facebook-like

When FB user "Likes" url "http://www.example.com/", does he also "Like" "http://www.example.com/index.php?a=10" and "http://www.example.com/somescript.php?g=6"?

I'm confused, help please! I've got an app run through a page tab at fb page and need my this app to detect if user has liked that page.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Each one, in the eyes of Facebook, are completely different URLs.

In an ideal world, you would set your htacess file to use friend URL's so that all the "liker" and "facebook" would ever see, is the same URL.

Comment: ok then. But I've got an app run through a page tab at fb page and need my this app to detect if user has liked that page.

Is that possible?

Comment: When you say detect, do you mean for using it in code, or, to simply show to a user on another page that THAT page has been liked? If thats the case then you can use this...

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=254584611241306&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="URL OF PLACE TO LIKE HERE" send="false" layout="box_count" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>